# I am getting an error of "can not read object" in weka when i try to load a ".arff" extension file

Tags: arff

File type is already chosen as arff so the problem is not there.
Furthermore, it asked notified that "can not determine file loader automatically, choose one". So I have chosen ArffLoader.
But after this when I try to open .arff file it gives "couldn't read object" error. [screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muDMd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably clicked on the **Open...** button in the bottom left corner of the GenericObjectEditor dialog. The *Open* and *Save* buttons there are for loading/saving configured objects aka the setup that you are currently viewing in the GenericObjectEditor (when hovering with the mouse over the button you will get hints displayed accordingly). Instead of clicking on the **Open...*** button, you need to click on the **OK** button, to accept and apply the configured object (in your case the file loader).

[image]